# Best way to show message in Controller

Tags: php

Which way is the best to show message in Controller? Is must showing count articles.

```
$c = count($articles);

if($c == 0) {
  return "On site are 0 articles";
} elseif ($c == 1){
  return "On site is 1 article";
} else {
  return "On site are" . $c . "articles";
}
```

or:

```
if($c == 1) {
  $text1 = 'is';
  $text2 = 'article'
} else {
  $text1 = 'are';
  $text2 = 'articles'
}

return "On site" . $text1 . $c . $text2;
```

Maybe others ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use an external pluralization class.

A short Google research returned this: http://kuwamoto.org/2007/12/17/improved-pluralizing-in-php-actionscript-and-ror/

Use it like:

```
echo 'On site ' . $c==1 ? 'is ' : 'are ' . isInflect.pluralize_if($c, 'article') . '.';
```

Pretty sure there are other libraries which also pluralize/singularize the verb (is/are).

Answer (score 0):

```
if($c > 0))
{
    return "There are $c article(s) on this site.";
}
else
{
    return "There are no articles on this site.";
}
```

Something like that?

Comment: You're sort of neglecting that the OP is trying to *properly* pluralize the word "article".